# right design for special consts meaning like re * or +, friendly reading

Tags: python, regex

in order to build a kind of multi level regular expression engine that will operating on items inside lists, i am looking for a good design idea. This is the background.

so i will have list of lisst, each item can be seen as a string (or text),

i would like to have others kind of lists that will match these lists and as matcher will allow some operators like the one available in regular expression : `*, *?, +, +?`

so that i can write matcher based upon `['this', '*', 'star']` meaning i'm looking for `'this'`, followed by zero or many item, then ending at `'star'`.

my question is about the `'*'` and others operators, what is the right pythonic design to do so this i can also actually search for `'*'`, without having to start to protect it like in `'\*'`and starting to handle the typical `\\` problem (btw may be is there already a parser available so that it can be easy?)

will having global constants like below (i mean const that value an int, while my items are string/text/re.compiled pattern) would be a good design idea? thus having

`['this', MyConst.ZERO_MANY, 'star']`  rather than `['this', '*', 'star']`

so that i can also have matcher `['this', MyConst.ZERO_MANY, 'star', with', '*']` that will match for lists like :

```
['this', 'star', with', '*']
['this', 'is', 'with', 'many', 'words', 'before', 'star', 'with', '*']
```

while with directly using '*' as both meaning, i will need some special escaping like stuff, like in matcher

```
['this', 
 '*', # operator for zero or many
'star',
'with', 
 '\ *' # some hint to say, this time it is not my operator but searching for item('*')
 ]`
```

(doing it this way, while using list matcher, i will have first to check the type of item, and if it is an `int` look for its special meaning , i feel this is not ok with python way of life)

do you have betters suggestions please? or doing it this way i a non sense idea, if so, please why?

actually, the list used for the matcher, are string, but can also be a regular expression compiled pattern, and they operate at the item level, while i also need a way to express that i am operating as the list sequence itself so that i can say, "we allow having some items before having something else"

```
class MyConst:
    ZERO_MANY = 1
    NON_GREEDY_ZERO_MANY = 2
    ONE_MANY = 3
    NON_GREEDY_ONE_MANY = 4
```

best regards

Comment: If you already have a class, putting the constants there is an option if you only need them in there or they are very related to that class. Otherwise just make them globals in your module. Python has proper scoping so doing so is perfectly fine (unlike in a "language" like PHP where you'd pollute the (most) global scope with them)

Comment: well, more than an opinion-based, i shoud have written that i'm interested in what will be the right pythonic way to do this! my question was not on where i should put the constants, but how to implements this kind of of behaviour to avoid `'*'`

Comment: Reopened; please edit the question so it's clear that you are looking for the pythonic way and not for opinions what people believe is a pretty way to do it.

Comment: ok, i just rephrase, thx

Comment: Maybe I'm not getting the question right, but have you seen the `re.escape` method? http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.escape

Comment: well, may be you point me something interesting... not about the re.escape, but i may fell ok with my 'int' const idea to have think like re.LOCALE (int value for 4) or RE.IGNORECASE (int value for 2)?

Comment: Could you please provide some example inputs and expected outputs. Do you intend to treat each element in the list as a (regex) character or is matching required within each element as well?

Comment: yes you are right, item inside the matcher list can be a string, or a regular expression matching a string, and i need some special way to mean that i am operating not on item level, but on the sequence of items themselves...

Comment: edited and added some code